# Reading in a complex text file to input into database

Tags: c#

I am working on a program that will read in a text file and then insert areas of the text file into different columns on a database. The text file is generally set up like this:

```
"Intro information"

"more Intro information"

srvrmgr> "information about system"

srbrmgr> list parameters for component *ADMBatchProc*

"Headers"
*Name of record*  *alias of record*  *value of record*
```

The columns create a table containing all of the setting information for this component. One all of the settings are listed, the file moves to another component and returns all the information for that component in a new table. I need to read in the component and the information on the tables without the headers or the other information. I will then need to be able to transfer that data into a database. The columns are fixed width on each table within the file.

Any recommendations about how to approach this are welcome. I have never read in a file this complex so I dont really know how to approach ignoring alot of information while trying to get other information ready for a database. Also the component value I am trying to gather always follows the word component on a line that starts with "srvrmgr".

The '*' represents areas that will be put into datbase.

```
Siebel Enterprise Applications Siebel Server Manager, Version 8.1.1.11 [23030] LANG_INDEPENDENT 
Copyright (c) 1994-2012, Oracle. All rights reserved.

The Programs (which include both the software and documentation) contain
proprietary information; they are provided under a license agreement     containing
restrictions on use and disclosure and are also protected by copyright,    patent,
and other intellectual and industrial property laws. Reverse engineering,
disassembly, or decompilation of the Programs, except to the extent required to
obtain interoperability with other independently created software or as    specified
by law, is prohibited.

Oracle, JD Edwards, PeopleSoft, and Siebel are registered trademarks of
Oracle Corporation and/or its affiliates. Other names may be trademarks
of their respective owners.

If you have received this software in error, please notify Oracle  Corporation
immediately at 1.800.ORACLE1.

Type "help" for list of commands, "help <topic>" for detailed help

Connected to 1 server(s) out of a total of 1 server(s) in the enterprise

srvrmgr> configure list parameters show PA_NAME,PA_ALIAS,PA_VALUE

srvrmgr> 

srvrmgr> list parameters for component ADMBatchProc

PA_NAME                                                                     PA_ALIAS                               PA_VALUE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
----------------------------------------------------------------------  -------------------------------------  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
ADM Data Type Name                                                         ADMDataType                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
ADM EAI Method Name                                                         ADMEAIMethod                           Upsert                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
ADM Deployment Filter                                                     ADMFilter       

213 rows returned.

srvrmgr> list parameters for component ADMObjMgr_enu

PA_NAME                                                                 PA_ALIAS                               PA_VALUE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
----------------------------------------------------------------------  -------------------------------------  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
AccessibleEnhanced                                                      AccessibleEnhanced                     False
```

This is the beginning of the text file. It a produced in a system called Siebel to show all of the settings for this environment. I need to pull the component name (there are multiple on the actual file but the ones shown here are 'ADMBatchProc' and 'ADMObjMgr_enu'), and then the data shown on the table below it that was created by Siebel. The rest of the information is irrelevant for the purpose of the task I need.

Comment: I did not find the explanation very clear, could you give a concrete example, showing what do you mean by columns, components... ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Test-Driven Development techniques in this case. I'm guessing that your possible variations of input format are near infinite.

Try this:

1)  Create an interface that will represent the data operations or parsing logic you expect the application to perform. For example:

```
public interface IParserBehaviors {
    void StartNextComponent();
    void SetTableName(string tableName);
    void DefineColumns(IEnumerable<string> columnNames);
    void LoadNewDataRow(IEnumerable<object> rowValues);
    DataTable ProduceTableForCurrentComponent();
    // etc.
}
```

2) Gather as many small examples of discrete inputs that have well-defined behaviors as possible.

3) Inject a behaviors handler into your parser. For example:

```
public class Parser {
    private const string COMPONENT_MARKER = "srvrmgr";
    private readonly IParserBehaviors _behaviors;
    public Parser(IParserBehaviors behaviors) {
        _behaviors = behaviors;
    }
    public void ReadFile(string filename) {
        // bla bla
        foreach (string line in linesOfFile) {
            // maintain some state
            if (line.StartsWith(COMPONENT_MARKER)) {
                DataTable table = _behaviors.ProduceTableForCurrentComponent();
                // save table to the database
                _behaviors.StartNextComponent();
            }
            else if (/* condition */) {
                // parse some text
                _behaviors.LoadNewDataRow(values);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

4) Create tests around the expected behaviors, using your preferred mocking framework. For example:

```
public void FileWithTwoComponents_StartsTwoNewComponents() {
    string filename = "twocomponents.log";
    Mock<IParserBehaviors> mockBehaviors = new Mock<IParserBehaviors>();
    Parser parser = new Parser(mockBehaviors.Object);

    parser.ReadFile(filename);

    mockBehaviors.Verify(mock => mock.StartNextComponent(), Times.Exactly(2));
}
```

This way, you will be able to integrate under controlled tests. When (not if) someone runs into a problem, you can distill what case wasn't covered, and add a test surrounding that behavior, after extracting the case from the log being used. Separating concerns this way also allows your parsing logic to be independent from your data operation logic. The needs of parsing specific behaviors seems to be central to your application, so it seems like a perfect fit for creating some domain-specific interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to read the text file using StreamReader:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    byte[] data = new byte[fileStream.Length];
    for (int index = 0; index < fileStream.Length; index++)
    {
        data[index] = (byte)fileStream.ReadByte();
    }
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data)); // Displays: your file - now you can decide how to manipulate it.
}
```

Perhaps then you'll use [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) to capture the date you'd like to insert:

You might insert into the db like this:

```
using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(
        “INSERT INTO People ([FirstName], [LastName], [MiddleInitial])
        VALUES(‘John’, ‘Doe’, null)”,
        connection);
        SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(
        “INSERT INTO People ([FirstName], [LastName], [MiddleInitial])
        VALUES(‘Jane’, ‘Doe’, null)”,
        connection);
        command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    transactionScope.Complete();
}
```

Examples adapted from Wouter de Kort's C# 70-483.